# Jmeter - how to properly send request name and reason on assertion failure

Tags: java, email, jmeter, automated-tests

I am new to jmeter (I am using version 3.3) and I created a test plan with the goal of sending an email on Assertion failure.

in this email I want to add some information about the name of the request and its reason

so I have added and **if controller** with this condition:

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

[image]

a beanshell preprocess with this script:

[image]

and an SMTP Sampler with this body:

[image]

and a response assertion:

[image]

I want to get an email anytime it hits the condition of response code=500 and the info described above.

I got to receive the email on that condition but the body message is literally this:

${body}

this is the assertion result:

[image]
what am I doing wrong?

How to get what I need?

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind your IF controller? because the way i see it, the script will only send an email if the last sample is ok, therefore there will be no data in the assertion to add it to your variable "body" because the sampler didnt fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `prev` variable is not defined in the Beanshell PreProcessor (it exists only for PostProcessor and Listener, I would suggest using `ctx.getPreviousResult()` instead where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html) instance.

You also need to enable your `HTTP Request GET - posts` as this will be this "previous result" you're interested in.

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language on next available opportunity. You should be even able to re-use the same code as I don't see any Beanshell-specific features in it. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Comment: thanks Dmitri, please what do u mean with prev variable?

Comment: Your `prev.getAssertionResults()` should be replaced with `ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults()`

Comment: I am getting a null in the body of the email

Comment: You have to move your post request and put it before the if controller and leave the SMTP sampler alone in the if controller

Answer (score 0):

The script is sending an email if the last sampler is ok, therefore the assertion is ok too, so the `body` variable won't hold any value.

Just adjust your if statement to `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`, and then move up your HTTP sampler `HTTP Request - POST/articles` above the if controller.

This will make your script send an email if the sampler failed and you will have the `body` variable holding the failure message.

Comment: adjusting the script with this condition !${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}, the script doesnt run at all

Comment: just to be clear, you want the script to send an email if the HTTP Requests - get -post fails right? have you enabled this sampler?

Comment: yes, I want to achieve it, please see my next update

Comment: I still see that the HTTP Request - GET - posts sampler is disabled

Comment: I thought this was irrelevant as long as I want to test the other request (post article)